# Inheritance static member separate for each class

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, typescript

The class A and B are holding the same address reference to the config member. How can I separate them?

```
class ConfigModel {

    public static config = []

    public foo() {
        //Code
    }

}

class A extends ConfigModel {

}

class B extends ConfigModel {

}
```

Comment: What would you like them to have? Separate them how?

Comment: A and B have the config member. But if I add something to A.config, B.config should not have it

Comment: ...then why is config static??

Comment: not every instance should have a config copy

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn't extend, then, you should use a has-a relationship, then some classes can have their own configs and some can share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the following:

```
class ConfigModel {
  static get config () {
    return this._config = this._config || [];
  }
}

class A extends ConfigModel {
}

class B extends ConfigModel {
}

A.config.push(1);
B.config.push(2);

console.log(A.config); // [1]
console.log(B.config); // [2]
```

All it does it to define the static property on the fly once accessed for the first time. Hope it helps!

Comment: this is awesome. For TypeScript I only add the `private static _config` and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the static array of `ConfigModel` into new static members in `A` and `B`:

```
class ConfigModel {
    public static config = [1, 2];
}

class A extends ConfigModel {
    public static config = ConfigModel.config.slice(0);
}

class B extends ConfigModel {
    public static config = ConfigModel.config.slice(0);
}

console.log(ConfigModel.config); // [1, 2]
console.log(A.config); // [1, 2]
console.log(B.config); // [1, 2]

A.config.push(3);
console.log(ConfigModel.config); // [1, 2]
console.log(A.config); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(B.config); // [1, 2]

B.config.pop();
console.log(ConfigModel.config); // [1, 2]
console.log(A.config); // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(B.config); // [1]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20ConfigModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20config%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20A%20extends%20ConfigModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20config%20%3D%20ConfigModel.config.slice(0)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20ConfigModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20config%20%3D%20ConfigModel.config.slice(0)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(ConfigModel.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%0Aconsole.log(A.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%0Aconsole.log(B.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%0A%0AA.config.push(3)%3B%0Aconsole.log(ConfigModel.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%0Aconsole.log(A.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0Aconsole.log(B.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%0A%0AB.config.pop()%3B%0Aconsole.log(ConfigModel.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%5D%0Aconsole.log(A.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0Aconsole.log(B.config)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B1%5D))

Comment: I dont want to add on every class the config member. For testing atm, the member is public. In the future it will be private.